# plesk error when trying repair database

Tags: mysql, windows, plesk

I am trying to repair the plesk but I am having [this 
error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYOsz.png), the panel is not working and is giving the 503 error

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give any information about your system (OS, Plesk version, system logs), we also don't know what you did prior the issues came up and how you tried to deal with them.

Anyway, I would recommend you to read Plesk documentation which might help, [see the Plesk Repair Utility section here](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/plesk-administration/plesk-repair-utility.74649/).

Seems like you are having issues with your database, you can try to run `plesk repair db` to try and repair any database issues Plesk might detect, or `plesk repair all` to repair all aspects on your server.

Comment: Hi, sorry for that, is Windows 2008 server R2, the plesk version is 11.0.9. just one thing the command Plesk is not recognized, and I can't find on plesk folder, but will try. Thank You

Comment: Seems like you are running a quite old installation of Plesk, unfortunately Plesk's repair tool didn't exist back then.
In this case you should check your SQL server's logs for any clues of what is wrong with your installation, try to Google for any error messages you get in there.
I also recommend you to upgrade to a newer version, if possible.